# Копирование элементов массива объектов

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. 
Как видно из кода и скрина консоли при копировании элементов массива объектов через третью переменную, массив, в который копируются значения состоит из одинаковых элементов, а именно последнего скопированного элемента. Почему так происходит?

```
var obj=[
    {name:"Jose",
    id:1},
    {name:"George",
    id:2},
    {name:"John",
    id:3},
    {name:"Stan",
    id:4},
    {name:"Mark",
    id:5},
];

var element={
    name:"",
    id:""
};

var newArr=[];

element.name=obj[0].name;
element.id=obj[0].id;
console.log(element);
newArr[0]=element;
element.name=obj[1].name;
element.id=obj[1].id;
console.log(element);
newArr[1]=element;

console.log(newArr);
```

[image: Скрин консоли]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://learn.javascript.ru/object-reference

> В переменной, которой присвоен объект, хранится не сам объект, а «адрес его места в памяти», иными словами – «ссылка» на него.

Таким образом, первая запись в консоли показывает первое состояние объекта, вторая — второе состояние этого же объекта, а третья выводит массив, элементы которого ссылаются на один и тот же объект. Поэтому мы дважды видим актуальное состояние этого объекта.

Answer (score 3):

После выполнения кода все три сущности newArr[0], newArr[1] и element указывают на одну и ту же область памяти. Т.е. при попытке изменения одного из них - изменения будут во всех. Попробуйте изменить newArr[0] и выведя в лог newArr[1] и element вы увидите изменения.